# Are posts at 8 foot intervals adequate for an 8 foot high fence?

Tags: fence

I have a 6 foot  wood fence that is using metal poles in concrete in a retaining wall.  The poles in the retaining wall are spaced about 94 inches apart.  Fence has existed without issue for 16 years.

I’m replacing fence with 8 foot wood board on board.  We will use existing poles but add extension on top of poles for extra 2 feet.

I got a call from contractor who said they need to add more poles since we are going to 8 feet ($1200 extra)? He said existing poles at 94 inches may not prevent bending in a bad storm?  Are existing poles at 94 inches apart enough since they are metal in concrete in a retaining wall?  Contractor said he would install fence with existing poles only and extension but not provide a warranty.

Alternatively, would reducing fence height to 7 feet eliminate the issue?  It appears most fence contractors treat 6 and 7 feet fences the same re post spacing?

Comment: Get some quotes from a few contractors.  We can give you our opinions but we won't be doing the work.

Comment: The contractor does have a valid point. Extend the post 2' up increases the area exposed to the wind resulting in the post been overstressed by approximately 80% with the same wind intensity. You either need stronger posts or reduce the post spacing.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the posts themselves? If they're 4x4" square, they'd probably work just fine, if they're small, round, standard chain-link sized posts, they may not be sufficient. Also, how are the extensions being added? Inserting a connector then dropping new metal on top & welding? That's a fair bit of work. Dropping a new, taller post around the existing post? That's a fair bit of material. The price quoted may not be too bad, all things considered. How many new posts will be added & what's the spacing? Will the spacing be uneven? Not good...

Comment: Wind loading may fold your existing poles over that have been fine. In costal areas going that high requires more in the ground also. It is a code issue so the contractor may not have a choice. I have seen homeowners put up fences then the building inspector come through and make them add posts unless they wanted to remove the existing ones and go deeper. Where are you located?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Take the [tour] to see how the Question & Answer format here differs from the general discussion format you'll see at most places. We want _one_ question with applicable answers, not a free-flowing, on going discussion.